# Potentially elementary question on affine functions on Banach spaces

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, affine-geometry

In *Measures Which Agree On Balls* by Hoffmann-Jørgensen, it is claimed that the function defined on $T(x)$, the set of normals to the unit sphere at $x$, given by

$ \varphi(x^*) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \lambda_i & \text{if } x^* = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i^* \in G \\
+\infty & \text{if } x^* \in T(x) \backslash G
\end{array}
\right. $

is affine if $G$ is a face of $T(x)$, that is, $G$ is convex and for all $x\in G$, $y \in T(x)\setminus G$, we have the line segment $(x,y] \cap G=\varnothing$. I do not understand this claim, and I don't know if I even understand the definition of affine. Does affine just mean that $\phi(x^*)=L(x^*)+b$, where $L$ is linear and $b \in \mathbb{R}$? How can such a function attain a value of infinity? Not sure if this is more appropriate here or on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f$ from a linear (or, more generally, affine) space $A$ is affine ([see e.g. this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632094/how-to-gain-an-intuition-of-the-affine-functions-definition)) if for all $a$ and $b$ in $A$ and all real $t$ one has $f((1-t)a+tb)=(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$. If $f$ is affine and $f(a)=\infty$ for some $a\in A$, then (taking, say, $t=2$, we have)
$$f(a)=f((1-2)a+2a)=(1-2)f(a)+2f(a)=-\infty+\infty,$$
which cannot have a meaning.

So, you are right: an affine function cannot possibly take the value $\infty$.

---

Also, without the condition (missing in the paper) that the $x^*_i$ be pairwise distinct, the function $\varphi$ will not be well defined. (Take e.g. the case when $n=2$, $x^*_1=x^*_2$, but $a_1\ne a_2$.)

Comment: Thank you! I think it's safe to assume that the $x_i^*$ are pairwise distinct. It seems that the main conclusion of the paper depends on this $\varphi$ being affine, so is the paper simply invalid?

Comment: You probably already have access to the paper, but just in case you don't, it is available free online [here](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/11610/9626).

Comment: @ilikemath : I have not read all the paper, but suspect that the results should remain valid. Perhaps, it is enough to define $\varphi$ only on $G$. I think you can check that.

Comment: @ilikemath : Thanks, I have the paper.

Comment: Only "thank you very much; your help has been invaluable and I really appreciate it." Marked as accepted.